GraphDB RDF file upload just goes on forever
I have been trying to upload a 3 MB RDF file and the upload just freezes and never stops:

This does not happen with other files like the ones provided for the tutorials.
Has anyone had any similar issue before?
I read on another post about validating the RDF file and even though I tried this, nothing changed.

Hello, you can send an email to graphdb-support@ontotext.com with the problematic rdf.

Have you been able to resolve this? Can you provide more information, e.g. GraphDB version, any error messages in the logs, or an RDF snippet to reproduce the problem?
